# Setting a variable in a one-liner Bash script

Tags: bash, case

Looking for a way to set a variable, in a bash one-liner, that is a script, such as:

```
export class={read -p "What Is Your Profession?" a; case $a in "Theif") echo "Stealth" ; in "Cleric") echo "Heals?" ; "Monk") echo "Focus?" ; *) echo "invalid choice" a; esac}
```

Although I'm having issues running this command without setting it to a one-liner, I've tried it numerous ways and I have gotten no results. The above was just the most clearly laid out in my eyes. I've also tried `VAR= ,`

The case itself gives me a

```
-jailshell: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

whenever I run it with more than one case. I know this is probably all jumbled up.

Comment: There are several issues here. First, you need a single string after a `=`, and curly braces are no string delimiters. Try single quotes, as in `var='long complex command'`. Next, you should never need to assign a command to a variable. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 14):

You need double-semicolons `;;` to separate the clauses of a `case` statement, whether it is one line or many.  You also have to be careful with `{ … }` because it is used for I/O redirection.  Further, both `{` and `}` must be tokens at the start of a command; there must be a space (or newline) after `{` and a semicolon (or ampersand, or newline) before `}`.  Even with that changed, the assignment would not execute the code in between the braces.  For that, you could use command substitution:

```
export class=$(read -p "What Is Your Profession?" a; case $a in "Theif") echo "Stealth" ;; "Cleric") echo "Heals?" ;; "Monk") echo "Focus?" ;; *) echo "invalid choice $a";; esac)
```

Finally, you've not run a spell-check on 'Thief'.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one-liner you can use:

```
export class=`{ read -p "What Is Your Profession? " a; case $a in "Theif") echo "Stealth";; "Cleric") echo "Heals?";; "Monk") echo "Focus?";; *) echo "invalid choice" a;; esac; }`
```

OR better you can just put this inside a function:

```
function readclass() { read -p "What Is Your Profession? " a; case $a in "Theif") echo "Stealth";; "Cleric") echo "Heals?";; "Monk") echo "Focus?";; *) echo "invalid choice" a;; esac; }
```

Then use it:

```
export class=$(readclass)
```